# Streaming baxter camera feed to phone using android app

Tags: ros, camera, rosjava, baxter, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I'm making an app in android tor baxter and one of its features is the camera.

So what the camera activity does is, the user can select which camera it wants (left hand, right hand and head) and then the camera from baxter is broadcasted to the users phone in which they can see what baxter sees on their phone and take a photo with a button.

I know you can see a live feed using rviz on ubuntu but I'm stuck on how to implement it into android.

Any idea how to get started?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281317/streaming-baxter-camera-feed-to-phone-using-android-app/) by [fc23](https://answers.ros.org/users/33408/fc23/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @fc23!

You will need ROS Android stuff. You can go to https://wiki.ros.org/android to get started and create a new package/ project from scratch.
Another option (perhaps a bit faster) would be to take a look at https://github.com/rosjava/android_apps. You can use [teleop](https://github.com/rosjava/android_apps/tree/kinetic/teleop) app as a template, remove what you don't need and build your app on top of that. You will see that this app has a place where an image stream can be visualized; you can probably grab that and tweak it to meet your needs.

If you won't use any custom service or message, you should be able to build your app using Gradle as a regular Android app without installing anything else just with Android Studio.
You can also do it the catkin-way; in that case you will need to install rosjava and it's build tools. Check https://wiki.ros.org/rosjava for installation tutorials (personal recommendation: go to source installation).

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2018-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2018-02-08**:
@fc23 were you able to get started? Do you need anything else...?

**Comment by [fc23](https://answers.ros.org/users/33408/fc23/) on 2018-02-08**:
@jubeira hi, I was able to get started using a socket server I found online, here is my post regarding it : https://answers.ros.org/question/281960/camera-image-as-a-string-baxter/